# How to detect without the system method or system framework with DTrace on Mac OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, user-defined-functions, dtrace

How do I just print the user-defined class and method using [DTrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace), without the system class, method, such as NSLock, NSThread, NSObject and so on?

Using the following D code, it can trace all of the Objective-C methods including the system and user-defined:

```
objc$target:::entry
{
    printf("%s %s\n", probemod, probefunc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

DTrace knows only about kernel and user spaces. It knows nothing about what libraries are part of system and what don't.

If you follow Cocoa conventions and properly prefix all you classes then you can specify the prefix in the name of probe. E.g. if your prefix is `VIC`:

```
objc$target:VIC*::entry
{
   printf("%s %s\n", probemod, probefunc);
}
```

These probe will be fired only if the passed class prefixed with VIC.

Comment: I want to just monitor the user-defind ( my code ).. I know , use "VIC" such prefix , can just got the class with VIC, is it another way?

Comment: You can create [USDT provider](http://blogs.oracle.com/dap/entry/writing_a_dtrace_usdt_provider) and call it everywhere you want to trace.